# Overriding the method and subscribing to the event is the same?

Tags: events, c#-4.0

```
class A
{
  public event EventHanler MyEvent;
  protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
  {
    if (MyEvent!=null) 
        MyEvent(this, e);
  }

   public void DoEvent()
   {
    //................
      MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());
   }
}




class B: A
{
  private A a = new A();
  public B ()
  {
    a.MyEvent += MyMethod;
  }
  public void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Event handler");
  }
}



class C : A
{
  private A a = new A();

   protected override void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
   {
     base.OnMyEvent(e); 
     Console.WriteLine("OnMyEvent overriding");
  }
}
```

I subscribe to the event and override the method OnMyEvent() in the classes `B` and `C`. Pay attension calling the method `base.OnMyEvent(e)` is in the beginning of the method `C.OnMyEvent(...)`.

As far as I'm concerned there are no differences here. In other words if I call `base.OnMyEvent(e)` in the beginning of the overriding method, it would mean the same as I just subscribe to the event?

Are there actually no differences?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference:

- Invoking `C.OnMyEvent()` **raises** `MyEvent`. (Conversely, raising `MyEvent` will not invoke `C.OnMyEvent()`.)
- `B.MyMethod` **handles** `MyEvent`. Thus, raising `MyEvent` will invoke `B.MyMethod`. (Conversely, invoking `B.MyMethod` will not raise `MyEvent`.)

Comment: In the other words: if I want to handle the event `A.MyEvent` is there any difference of the handling it in the class `B` and in the class `C`?

Comment: The way it is written right now, class `B` is handling the event but class `C` is not. So yes, that is a huge difference.